# Compiler error in c function for c166 16 bit microprocessor

Tags: c

Currently, I am trying to resolve several issues in a REALLY old c166 16bit microprocessor code. I have basic knowledge with c but not with microprocessors or c166, therefore I have zero clue what the compiler is trying to tell me. Maybe some of you guys know what is going on here / aka help me to resolve this compiler error:

### Code

```
void ChecksummenBerechnenFar(word wAnzahlByte, byte far* bP_AnfangSpeicher)
{
word wChecksum;
word wCount;
  for(wChecksum=0xFFFF, wCount=0; wCount < (wAnzahlByte-2); wCount+=1 ) {
     wChecksum -= *bP_AnfangSpeicher++;
  }

  *bP_AnfangSpeicher = (byte) (wChecksum & 0x00FF);
  bP_AnfangSpeicher++;
  *bP_AnfangSpeicher = (byte) (wChecksum >>8);

}
```

### Error

```
compiling CHECKS.C...
\CHECKS.C(8): error C25: syntax error near 'wAnzahlByte'
\CHECKS.C(9): warning C35: 'ChecksummenBerechnenFar': uses old-style declarator
\CHECKS.C(10): error C25: syntax error near 'wChecksum'
\CHECKS.C(10): warning C34: 'wChecksum': missing declaration specifiers
\CHECKS.C(11): warning C34: 'wCount': missing declaration specifiers
\CHECKS.C(11): error C42: 'wCount': not in formal parameter list
\CHECKS.C(12): error C25: syntax error near 'for'
\CHECKS.C(12): error C25: syntax error near '='
\CHECKS.C(12): error C25: syntax error near '<'
\CHECKS.C(12): error C25: syntax error near '-'
\CHECKS.C(12): error C25: syntax error near '+='
\CHECKS.C(13): error C25: syntax error near '-='
\CHECKS.C(13): error C25: syntax error near '++'
\CHECKS.C(16): error C67: 'byte': undefined identifier
\CHECKS.C(17): error C25: syntax error near '++'
\CHECKS.C(18): error C53: redefinition of 'bP_AnfangSpeicher'
\CHECKS.C(18): error C67: 'byte': undefined identifier
\CHECKS.C(20): error C25: syntax error near '}'
\CHECKS.C(20): error C7: compilation aborted
```

Comment: `word` and `byte` are not in the standard C and it seems they should be declared (or a header with declarations of them should be included).

Comment: What's a c166, and what does it have to do with x86?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C166_family says it's some kind of RISC, so it seems nothing to do with the [tag:x86] tag.  Were the `byte` and `word` types from some x86 header?  I guess `byte far *` is probably also legacy x86 code, unless this C166 ISA also has segmentation / far pointers?  Why are you trying to write x86-16 code for C166?

Comment: The code above is part of an old operating system I have to rewrite. It runs on an old 16bit microprocessor. You can get more infos [here](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/274602/SiemensSemiconductorGroup/SAB80C166W/1). I've changed the tags now

Comment: I hope you have the hardware errata.  Those chips were buggy.

Comment: Being old and 16-bit doesn't mean they have anything in common!  x86 code for a "large" memory model with a mix of near vs. far pointers is probably not going to be easy to port, although you might get away with just `#define far /*empty*/`, and of course defining byte and word.

Comment: Your changed tag `x86-16` is wrong as well. C166 it not related to Intel 16 bit CPUs.

Comment: I hope for you that you don't really have to use a real C166 but another family member like C165/7 which are at least a tiny bit less ancient. ;)

Comment: No, I have to use C166 ._.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing a header file inclusion. Some data type might have been renamed using typedef somewhere.
If you are on a Linux host, I recommend installing "ctags" to browse through your code to find definitions and declarations.
For now you could do a grep in your source code directory
`"find -name *.h | grep -rn typedef | grep word"`
This will give you a file name and line number. open the file location and go to the line number check if that's the definition you are looking for.
If yes then include that file.

Comment: It was an header error. I've found out that "word" and "far" were declared in another header called "STDDEF.h"

Answer (score 2):

Commenters have mentioned that word and byte are not standard C and that’s true. But you aren’t seeing “undeclared identifier” errors.

I think that somehow the symbols word and byte have been #defined as empty strings. Maybe the #defines try to choose appropriate definitions based on the architecture you’re compiling for, and since you’re on a new architecture that it doesn’t recognize, they get converted into blank strings. You might be expected to pass in some kind of value via the -D switch that identifies the target architecture, especially if it’s different from the one you’re compiling on.

With the types replaced by empty strings, the compiler thinks you’re using the ancient K&R function definition syntax, and that’s why you’re seeing these errors.

Try compiling with -E to dump the preprocessor output and see what you get.

Comment: From the latest comment, it seems the OP has source for an x86-16, and is trying to compile it with a C166 compiler.  So all x86-specific stuff like byte and word is undefined, and so is `T far *` for x86 near vs. far pointer memory segmentation.  Interesting idea about empty string defines, though; that could explain the "old style" messages.

Comment: I've found out that "word" and "far" were declared in a header called "stddef.h". I've included the file and it worked. Thank you very much